# Categories and subcategories product hierarchy with Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I'm trying to build an Amazon like products-categories and subcategories hierarchy with Sails.js.

I started with [many-to-many relation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/many-to-many) and so far I've been able to achieve like half of it. What I got working til now is categories, and categories have products linked to it, below is an instance of it:

Computer Accessories -> Sapphire RX 580, Sapphire 5700XT, Corsair 550W PSU

Here's how the [many-to-many relation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/many-to-many) models look like:

```
    // Product.js
    
    module.exports = {
    
      attributes: {
    
        name: {
          type: 'string',
          required: true,
          unique: true,
          allowNull: false
        },
        keywords: {
          type: 'json',
          required: false
        },
        
        // Reference to Category
        category: {
          collection: 'category',
          via: 'product'
        },
    
      },
    }; 

   // Category.js

    module.exports = {
    
        attributes: {
            name: {
          type: 'string',
          required: true,
          unique: true
        },
        // Reference to Product
        product: {
          collection: 'product',
          via: 'category'
        }
      }
      
    };
```

What I want to build out of this is to have subcategories to categories, below is an instance of it:

Computer Accessories -> Graphic Cards -> Sapphire RX 580, Sapphire 5700XT

Computer Accessories -> Power Supplies -> Corsair 550W PSU

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and Sails. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could need something called **Reflexive Association**, then you may include something like that in *Category* model:

```
// api/models/Category.js

parent: {
  model: 'category'
}

children: {
  collection: 'category',
  via: 'parent'
}
```

If you need to save values:

```
const parentId = 1;
await Category.addToCollection(parentId, 'children').members([2, 3, 4]);
```

Then when you need to populate the relationship field:

```
const categories = await Category.find().populate('children');
```

Comment: That's exactly what i discovered after a little reading. This should be the correct answer, I'm giving it a shot.